# Reducing Predicate calls

Tags: list, prolog

I have this predicate:

```
check_matrix([[_, E2, E3], 
             [E4, E5, E6], 
             [E7, E8, E9]]) :-
     E5 = E9,
     is_valid([E4, E5, E6]),
     is_valid([E7, E8, R9]),
     is_valid([E2, E5, E8]),
     is_valid([E3, E6, E9]).
```

Which checks if my 2 x 2 matrix is valid, with the top left cell, `_` being completely ignored.The `E2`, `E3`, `E4` and `E7` cells are just headers for the 2 x 2 matrix.

Is their a nicer way I could `is_valid()`, whereby I don't need to call `is_valid()` 4 times. If the matrices get bigger, such as 5x5, this predicate would need to call `is_valid()` 10 times. Is this normal for Prolog? Or is their a more elegant way to do this?

I was thinking of just having another predicate which creates a nested list of of all the possible lists I want to pass to `is_valid()`, and call that predicate on each of the lists, then pass the result back to `check_matrix()`. I feel like their must be a more elegant way to do this. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

`E5 = E9` is just a diagonal checker, which checks if the diagonals of a matrix are the same, if they are not, then the predicate fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prolog has some libraries like `library(apply)` that provide *higher order predicates*: predicates where you pass another predicate.

A higher-order predicate that seems applicable here is [**`maplist/2`**](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/2). The predicate takes as arguments a predicate (`:Goal`) and a list (`?List`) and applies the `:Goal` on the elements of `?List` until a predicate fails, or the list is exhausted. You can somewhat compare it to a function in an imperative language that iterates over the list, and checks if the predicate holds for all the members of the list. Like for instance `all(..)` in Python.

We can thus use the following approach to check *all but the first row*:

```
:- use_module(library(apply)).

check_rows([_|T]) :-
    maplist(is_valid,T).
```

We however have to check all but the first column as well. Therefore we can use the [**`transpose/2`**](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=clpfd%3Atranspose/2) predicate. It takes two arguments and the second argument is the transpose of the first one. So:

```
?- transpose([[1, 2, 3], 
|             [4, 5, 6], 
|             [7, 8, 9]],X).
X = [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]].
```

So we can transpose the matrix, and then again use `maplist/2` to check all-but-the first rows of the *transpose* of the matrix `M`. So we can now implement the predicate like:

```
:- use_module(library(apply)).
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

check_matrix(M) :-
    M = [_|MT],
    maplist(is_valid,MT),
    transpose(M,[_|TT]),
    maplist(is_valid,TT).
```

**EDIT**:

In case you want to check if all but the first diagonal elements, I propose to define two additional predicates:

- `all_same/1` that checks if all the elements of the list are the same; and
- `diagonal/2` that constructs a list of diagonal elements.

`all_same/1` can be implemented as:

```
all_same([]).
all_same([_]).
all_same([H,H|T]) :-
    all_same([H|T]).
```

and `diagonal/2` can be obtained with:

```
diagonal(M,L) :-
    diagonal(M,0,L).

diagonal([],_,[]).
diagonal([R|RT],I,[D|DT]) :-
    nth0(I,R,D),
    I1 is I+1,
    diagonal(RT,I1,DT).
```

Now we can check the diagonal as follows:

```
check_matrix(M) :-
    M = [_|MT],
    maplist(is_valid,MT),
    transpose(M,[_|TT]),
    maplist(is_valid,TT),
    diagonal(M,[_|DT]),
    all_same(DT).
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid such hard-coded predicates you could try recursion:

You check for `is_valid` in each list (except first one) so you could write:

```
check_matrix([H|T]) :- is_valid_each_list(T),....

is_vqlid_each_list([]).
is_vqlid_each_list([L|T]):- length(L,3),is_valid(L),
                            is_vqlid_each_list(T).
```

Note that the restriction `length(L,3)` says the elements are lists of length 3 (or any parameter K if you wish, just add another parameter).

Now for checking `E2,E5,E8` (elements in same `position > 1`):

```
is_valid_pos(L):-length(L,3), is_valid_pos(L,1).

is_valid_pos(_,4).
is_valid_pos(L,K):- findall(X,(member(L1,L),nth0(K,L1,X)),L2),
                    is_valid(L2),K1 is K+1, is_valid_pos(L,K1).
```

So the full general solution:

```
check_matrix([H|T]) :- is_valid_each_list(T), is_valid_pos([H|T]).

is_vqlid_each_list([]).
is_vqlid_each_list([L|T]):- length(L,3),is_valid(L),
                            is_vqlid_each_list(T).

is_valid_pos(L):-length(L,3), is_valid_pos(L,1).

is_valid_pos(_,4).
is_valid_pos(L,K):- findall(X,(member(L1,L),nth0(K,L1,X)),L2),
                    is_valid(L2),K1 is K+1, is_valid_pos(L,K1).
```